# Flutter android Unhandled Exception: FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists (getting this error twice)

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies, audio-service

> I am using package [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service)

Issue - when I use the audio service package and try to run the app it returns an error where firebase is initialized.

[image: Error Log]

If I do not use the audio service package, the app is working fine, meaning no error message related to firebase.

Firebase Initialization Code:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    ).then((value) {
      logger.i('Firebase Initialized:${value.options}');
    });
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

If possible please guide me regarding this issue.

`main()` should get called once and firebase must initialize once.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
_audioHandler = await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => MyAudioHandler(),
    config: AudioServiceConfig(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.mycompany.myapp.channel.audio',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Music playback',
    ),
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but this is not working.

Comment: can you share the error

Comment: Same error as before

Comment: you need to initialize your audio service,(i changed my answer)

Comment: Documentation asks to add
<!-- EDIT THE android:name ATTRIBUTE IN YOUR EXISTING "ACTIVITY" ELEMENT -->
    <activity android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity" ...>
      ...
    </activity>

but there I have ".MainActivity"
So, shall I change to "com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity"
?

Comment: Audio Service is already initialized

Comment: use your package name and create new AudioServiceActivity then change the name to that

Comment: Sorry, but can you give an example?